# Compute Integral of $\int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{x}}dx$ using integration by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

> Compute Integral of $$\int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{x}}dx$$ using integration by substitution.

I will start from:

$\int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{x}}dx$

let $u= \sqrt{x}$, $du = -dx\rightarrow dx=-du$

Now I will start with substituting:

$\int_0^1 e^{u}-du\Longrightarrow -\int_0^1 e^{u}du $

$ e^{u}+C \Longrightarrow e^{\sqrt{x}}+C$

The problem is that I am not considering from $u=0$ to $ u=1$ $\rightarrow \int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{x}}$ and since i didn't really understood integrals i don't know how to implement it.

PS: I'm not sure that what I did is correct.

Comment: $du \neq -dx$.${}{}$

Comment: $x=u^2$, so $dx=2u\,du$.

Answer (score 3):

Your substitution is good, but you get the derivative wrong: since $x=u^2$, you should use
$$
dx=2u\,du
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^1 2ue^u\,du
$$
(because $x=0$ gives $u=\sqrt{0}=0$ and $x=1$ gives $u=\sqrt{1}=1$).

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Take $\sqrt{x}=t \implies \frac{1}{ 2\sqrt{x}}dx=dt \implies dx=2tdt$

$$\int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{x}}dx= 2 \int_0^1 te^{t}dt$$

Then apply Integration by parts.

Answer (score 2):

$u = \sqrt{x} $ gives $dx = 2u \, du $, so your integral becomes
$$ \int_0^1 2ue^{u} \, du = \left[ 2ue^{u} \right]_0^1 - 2\int_0^1 e^{u} \, du = 2e - 2\left[ e^{u} \right]_0^1 = 2 $$

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{x}}dx$

Substitute $\sqrt{x}=u$, $x=u^2$ $dx=2udu$ The limits are the same. So $\int_0^1e^u2udu=2\int_0^1ude^u=2ue^u|_0^1-2\int_0^1e^udu=2e-2(e^u|_0^1)=2e-2e+2=2$